# Want to display a image from the database with multiple quotes in query

Tags: php, mysql

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `Rorschach` WHERE Rid = $init");
$query2 = mysql_fetch_array($query);
    //$repd = $rep2[0];
$rid = $query2[0];
$rname = $query2[1];
$rimage = $query2[2];
echo '<div class='tab-pane active' id='profile'>
            <table class='table'>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>&nbsp;$rimage
                        <td class='td-actions text-right'>
                            <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($rimage['Rimage'] ).'" height="200" width="200" class="img-thumnail" />
                                <div class='radio'>
                                    <label>
                                       <font color='#777'>True</font> <input type='radio' name = '' value = '1'>
                                    </label>
                                    <label>
                                       <font color='#777'>False</font> <input type='radio' name = '' value = '0'>
                                    </label>
                                </div>



                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>';
```

When I use `$rimage` that time it showing an image without encoding so its not useful. 
When I use `<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($rimage['Rimage'] ).'" height="200" width="200" class="img-thumnail" />` Echo command does not execute this line because multiple quotes.

DB:

```
Rid || Rname || Rimage
====+========+=========
 1  ||  abc  || img.jpg
```

Comment: Then fix the badly quoted string

Comment: Please help me to correct that

Comment: @Ameya    Try This  <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($rimage );?>"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the problem with that line. You need to change almost everything.

In `echo '<div class='tab-pane active' id='profile'>`, you're opening your `echo` up in single quotes. That means everything else that is in HTML, like the class, needs to be in double quotes, except for any PHP code. If you opened your `echo` with double quotes, everything in HTML would be in single quotes, except for any PHP code.

Try this for your `echo` statement as this should work now:

```
echo '<div class="tab-pane active" id="profile">
    <table class="table">
            <tbody>
                <tr>&nbsp;'.$rimage.'
                    <td class="td-actions text-right">
                        <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode($rimage['Rimage'] ).'" height="200" width="200" class="img-thumnail" />
                        <div class="radio">
                            <label>
                               <font color="#777">True</font> <input type="radio" name = " " value = "1">
                            </label>
                            <label>
                               <font color="#777">False</font> <input type="radio" name = " " value = "0">
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>';
```